# How to create a generic wrapper class to extend any model

Tags: c#, generics

How would I add the same fields to an object without caring what other fields the original property has. For Example I wanted use the following

```
public class Wrapper<T> : T
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public DateTime CallDate { get; set; }
        }
```

but received the error `cannot derive from T because it is a parameter type`

More Details:

If I have an original model such as:

```
public class OriginalModel {
     public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to extend it into:

```
    public class ExtemdedOriginalModel {
         public string name { get; set; }
         public string Status { get; set; }
         public DateTime CallDate { get; set; }
    }
```

but I want it to be generic so that I can add the two additional properties without having to add an interface to all the classes I want to be able to extend.

Comment: It's not clear what you trying to do. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: I've added some more details in an edit.

Comment: Not generally possible; inheritance is a static affair in C#. Alternatives: explicit classes and copying with something like AutoMapper, `partial` types and code generation with T4 templates, dipping into `dynamic`, using `Dictionary` instances to capture the properties more generally, using extension methods, using a `ConditionalWeakTable` to "attach" arbitrary data to instances without keeping them alive unnecessarily.

Comment: Why not use inheritance?

Comment: Why not have a property of type `T` inside the class `Wrapper`? i.e. use composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

[Instead of **inheritance** you should use **composition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Or in other words you can easily create a generic wrapper that has the actual data as its **member**, instead of in its inheritance-chain:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CallDate { get; set; }

    public Wrapper(T data) { this.Data = data ; }
}
```

Now you can still "extend" any type:

```
var m = new Wrapper<int>(3);
m.Status = "MyStatus";
```

Comment: Even though it is a good advice it doesn't solve the OP's problem of extending objects (and not creating a wrapper; even though he calls the type Wrapper)

Comment: @Fabjan In many cases what OP **thinks** is the solution of his/her problem actually **causes** the problem. This is one of those examples, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that depending on `T` some random implementation should appear on the `Wrapper<T>` instances.

Though this is theoretically possible, the implementation of such a class is a nightmare: essentially you need to generate a concrete type dynamically with the members of `T` and you have to emit some implementation for them. For example, I guess you want to store your properties when you set them and return the stored values when you read them. Even a simple C# auto property has some codebehind with a backing field you need to dynamically emit into a generated instance.

This can be justified in very rare cases as the desired behavior. One of them can be when you want to mock some interface or abstract classes in unit tests, this is what [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) does, for example. So if this is the case you don't need to reinvent the wheel.